# PHP Combine ElseIf Statement to output on one line

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to modify a Wordpress theme, and in the specifications.php file, I have created two new items to display on the template. Individually they work fine - displaying one on top of the other, but I need them to be on the same line, in the format of:

MPG:  City - number   HWY - number

Instead, they are currently

MPG City: number
MPG Hwy: number

Here is the code showing them on top of each other:

```
elseif( $id == 'seek_property_mpg_city'){
$result[$id]['name'] = __('MPG City:', 'tfuse');
$result[$id]['value'] = $val['value'];
continue;
}    

elseif( $id == 'seek_property_mpg_hwy'){          
$result[$id]['name'] = __('MPG HWY:', 'tfuse');
$result[$id]['value'] = $val['value'];      
continue;
}
```

I've tried using the && property to combine them with this code, but I only get the line with the HWY MPG, not both City and HWY:

```
elseif( $id == 'seek_property_mpg_hwy' && 'seek_property_mpg_city' ){
$result[$id]['name'] = __('MPG:', 'tfuse');
$city_mpg         = apply_filters( 'tfuse_property_mpg_city', $val['value'] );
$hwy_mpg         = apply_filters( 'tfuse_property_mpg_hwy', $val['value'] );
$result[$id]['value']   = apply_filters('name', $city_mpg, $hwy_mpg);
continue;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can't modify the generated CSS (but I could add to it) which is why I'm trying to make a PHP solution.

Here is the generated code in case someone has a CSS solution:

```
<li class="even">
<span class="spec_name seek_property_mpg_city ">MPG City:</span>
<strong class="spec_value seek_property_mpg_city ">20</strong>
</li>
<li>
<span class="spec_name seek_property_mpg_hwy ">MPG HWY:</span>
<strong class="spec_value seek_property_mpg_hwy ">30</strong>
</li>
```

Comment: why not merge them into one item?

Comment: I would love to merge them into one item, but I can't get it to work with the code I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.your_class li{
display:inline;
}
```

use `display:inline;` to get your list-items in the same line.